# Jquery: one selection of a child within a parent of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of inputs that has several parents and then multiple children under each parent. there is only 2 levels.(see links below)

Under each parent I have check boxes (MUST USE checkboxes, rather than radio buttons) and should only allow a single selection of the children.

I am using the following code on a prior working example

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var checkedState = $(this).attr("checked");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).attr("checked", checkedState);
});
```

A working example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/H4Jv5/

The example that I need to try and get working is here http://jsfiddle.net/TXp6H/, based on the code its not looking at the parents - as a side the '..' indicates the child, however this .. will be removed so its not something that can be targeted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **1st:** Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` when changing property values. **2nd:** Use `.closest()` or `.parents()` instead of repetitive `.parent()`.

Comment: All checkboxes look the same. Is there anything that could help distinguish a parent from a child?